# Difference in Salary in Oracle Select Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

I have below table having three columns(Empno,Ename,Salary)

```
Empno  Ename  Salary 
101    Ashok  1000
102    Kumar  2000
103    Mani   3000
```

I need below Output by displaying difference in salary.

```
Empno Ename  Salary  Difference_in_Salary
101   Ashok  1000     1000
102   Kumar  2000     1000
103   Mani   3000     1000
```

Comment: How are you calculating your "difference"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to calculate a "difference" as it depends what you want the difference from:

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       ABS( salary - AVG( salary ) OVER () )                  AS difference_from_avg,
       LEAD( salary ) OVER ( ORDER BY salary ) - salary       AS difference_from_next,
       salary - LAG( salary, 1, 0 ) OVER ( ORDER BY salary )  AS difference_from_prev,
       salary - MIN( salary ) OVER ()                         AS difference_from_min,
       MAX( salary ) OVER () - salary                         AS difference_from_max
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( Empno, Ename, Salary ) AS 
SELECT 101, 'Ashok', 1000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102, 'Kumar', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103, 'Mani',  3000 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> EMPNO | ENAME | SALARY | DIFFERENCE_FROM_AVG | DIFFERENCE_FROM_NEXT | DIFFERENCE_FROM_PREV | DIFFERENCE_FROM_MIN | DIFFERENCE_FROM_MAX
> ----: | :---- | -----: | ------------------: | -------------------: | -------------------: | ------------------: | ------------------:
>   101 | Ashok |   1000 |                1000 |                 1000 |                 1000 |                   0 |                2000
>   102 | Kumar |   2000 |                   0 |                 1000 |                 1000 |                1000 |                1000
>   103 | Mani  |   3000 |                1000 |                 null |                 1000 |                2000 |                   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f858fd6b66316be96909bcfed6276f60)*